# How do I generate "code-first" EF classes from a script?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In our organization, changes to persistent data are made in the database first and then code is generated for whatever programs need to use it. This is non-negotiable. EF 6.1 includes a nice GUI-based mechanism for doing "database-first" for "code-first" classes. It works like a charm and we no longer have EDMX files holding us back from EF7. Huzzah!

There are five (big) tables in the database that *must* be excluded from the generation. We can't afford our classes to carry any relationships with that data. Since we will have to regenerate the whole set of classes every time the database changes, and there's no guarantee who will do the work, I don't want this to be a manual process, but a canned script that a tired or uninformed user can't fumble.

Is there any way to invoke the underlying work that the EF6.1 database-to-code wizard does from a command line or PowerShell script?

Comment: Is it a possibility for your organization to script the database to a new, temporary database without the five tables, and then generate the classes from that table instead?

Comment: You should have a look at the "EF Reverse POCO" template, it allows you to filter objects to your hearts desire

Comment: @OJ Raqueño - that will probably be hard for us to maintain. The development group doesn't "own" the database it's drawing from and the changes are few and far between. We're trying to script to avoid having to maintain side-skills that are being used seldom.

Comment: @ErikEJ - I'll definitely look into that one. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @ErikEJ - We're now using the EF Reverse POCO template and it is wonderful! Full featured, including stored procs and fakes for testing. Now that it has solved our original problem, I'll want to take advantage of the other possibilities it opens up. If your comment was an answer, I'd give it a checkbox as the "right answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the "EF Reverse POCO" template, it allows you to filter objects to your hearts desire! (And do so many other things!)